# Throwing an exception at line16

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;

namespace Rndom
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            start:
            Random obj = new Random();
            int num1 = obj.Next(1, 9);
            int num2 = obj.Next(10,21);
            Console.WriteLine("sum of two unique numbers\n"+num1+" "+num2+"  "+(num1+num2));
            char ch;
            Console.WriteLine("If wannt to continue, press y");
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey()); // <- I have exception thrown here
            if(ch=='y')
            {
                goto start;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("press any key to terminate");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is line 16?

Comment: What does this have to do with Unity3D? Also *what* exception is being thrown?

Comment: `ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` instead of `ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey());`

Comment: what type of object is Convert?

Comment: @Jasen [this kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Unity but when you find yourself using the `Main` function, `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadKey` in Unity you should understand that you are are not using Unity properly.

Comment: @Jasen it's not an object, but a static class that provides methods to convert from one type to another.

Comment: I recommend you post this code over on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are multiple issues that could use a thorough review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey());
```

You should put it as

```
ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Since `ConsoleKeyInfo` instance which is returned by `Console.ReadKey()` can't be just *converted* into `char`

Comment: Thank you sir! but i'm very new to c# can you explain a little more about your correct answer! Can the instance ConsoleKeyInfo can be converted to integer or any other type?

Comment: @ Adarsh Kumar: no; `ConsoleKeyInfo` can't be converted into integer - `int` by `Convert.ToInt32`; usually we use `Convert` with types which implement `IConvertible` interface. In (almost) all other cases you should look for a required *property*, `KeyChar` in your case

Comment: ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());   // i used this code instead of yours and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Adarsh Kumar: `ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());` is not the same: you are reading a line (e.g. `"bla-bla-bla"`) wait for enter key to be pressed (which starts a new line) and then try co convert the line (`"bla-bla-bla"`) to char and you have the `FormatException` with the message `'String must be exactly one character long.'`. If you prefer `Console.ReadLine()` either put it like this: `ch = Console.ReadLine()[0]` or check the input for the `Length == 1`